# Use Arduino Mega as I2C Slave with RPi3

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am trying to use Arduino Mega 2560 for extending I/Os of RPi3 with PWM and Analog Inputs. Infact I am not using RPi3 GPIO pins at all as maintaining two voltages for inputs 3.3 and 5 V is difficult.

Basically, I am trying to:

- 1. send an Array from RPi3 to set the outputs in Arduino and
- 2. send an Array from Arduino to RPi3 giving the status of Inputs.

Some values in the array could go as high as 10000.

I have been able to achieve the Number 1 above without the values higher than 255.

**Python Code**

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x06

def writeNumber(value):
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 1, [5,0,1,255, 6]) #dummy array as of now. This can go upto 50 values
    return -1


def readNumber():
    # number = bus.read_byte(address)
    data_received_from_Arduino = bus.read_byte(address)
    for i in data_received_from_Arduino:
       print(i)

    return number

while i1:
    writeNumber(1)
    readNumber()
```

**Arduino Code**

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x06
int number[50] = {0};
int inputs[100] = {0};

int state = 0;
int p=0; 

void setup() {
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

Serial.begin(9600); // start serial for output
// initialize i2c as slave
Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

// define callbacks for i2c communication
Wire.onReceive(receiveData);
Wire.onRequest(sendData);

Serial.println('Ready!');
}

void loop() {

//delay(1);
}

// callback for received data
void receiveData(int byteCount){
  Serial.println(byteCount);
  int p=0;
  while(Wire.available()) {
      number[p] = Wire.read();
      p++;
  }
    for(int k=0; k < 5; k++)  { 
    Serial.print( k);
    Serial.print( ":");
    Serial.println(number[k]); 
  }

}


// callback for sending data
void sendData(){  
  for(int k=0; k < 56;k++) {
  inputs[k] = digitalRead(k);
  Serial.print( k ); Serial.print(" : "); Serial.print(inputs[k]); 
  Serial.println(digitalRead(k));
  }
  Wire.write( inputs,56);
}
```

Can somebody guide? Does anyone know a sample Git for achieve the above. I can build it up for my application even if the sample is for a small array.

Comment: Is your question asking how to send 16-bit data from RPi to Arduino? Or about receiving 16-bit data on Arduino? Or about sending 16-bit data from Arduino back to RPi? Do you appreciate you need 16-bit data? Do you know how to split a 16-bit integer into 2 separate bytes? And how to re-assemble them? Are you happy to send 16-bit for each and every one of your 54 samples?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am basically looking for a piece of code to have two communication between Rpi3 and Mega by means of sending arrays with 16bit values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been playing around experimenting with sending and receiving four 16-bit numbers from a Raspberry Pi to an Arduino over I2C and got the following working.

Be aware that I am no expert in SMBus or I2C and I don't know if there are easier ways to do this. I am happy to retract my answer if anyone knows better!

Here's the code for the Raspberry Pi, it just sends four 16-bit numbers 100, 200, 1000, 10000 and then reads them back.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from smbus import SMBus
from time import sleep

bus = SMBus(1)
address = 0x08

def split(v):
    """Split 16-bit value into low and high bytes"""
    lobyte = v & 0xff
    hibyte = (v >> 8) & 0xff
    return lobyte, hibyte

def join(lo,hi):
    return lo | (hi << 8)

def Transmit():
    """Send 100, 200, 1000, 10000 on I2C"""
    a,b = split(100)
    c,d = split(200)
    e,f = split(1000)
    g,h = split(10000)
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, a,[b, c, d, e, f, g, h])

def Receive():
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0)
    i = join(block[0],block[1])
    j = join(block[2],block[3])
    k = join(block[4],block[5])
    l = join(block[6],block[7])
    print("{} {} {} {}".format(i,j,k,l))

Transmit()
sleep(1)
Receive()
```

---

On the Arduino side, I just read four 16-bit numbers from I2C, store them in an array and increment each one. When a read request comes in, I send back the four incremented numbers:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int address= 8;

#define N 4

// Last four 16-bit values we received
int16_t values[N];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Starting on i2c address:");
  Serial.println(address,DEC);
  Wire.begin(address);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

// callback for when data are received
void receiveEvent(int nBytes) {
  Serial.print("Received: ");
  Serial.println(nBytes);

  if(nBytes != 2 *N){
     Serial.print("I was expecting 8 bytes");

     return;
  }
  unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&values;
  for(int i=0;i<2*N;i++){
    *p++ = Wire.read();
  }
  // Increment all the values we received
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    values[i]++;
  }

}

// Callback for when data are read
void requestEvent() {

  Serial.println("Data requested");
  // Send back
 Wire.write((const uint8_t*)&values, N*2);
}
```

When I run the Python code on the Raspberry Pi, I get:

```
./i2c.py 
101 201 1001 10001
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The Python code gives the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/i2c/i2ctest.py", line 33, in <module>
    Transmit()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/i2c/i2ctest.py", line 23, in Transmit
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, a,[b, c, d, e, f, g, h])
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

Any Ideas?

Comment: Ummm! I started the Arduino code first, before the Python, if that helps? I ran `i2cdetect 1` on the Pi and saw the Arduino address listed. Ummm! You may need to add your `pi` user to the `dialout` group to give permission to access the `/dev/i2c` devices or run as root.

Comment: Thanks Mark for replying. My arduino Mega was being powered from my RPi3. Gave USB suply to Arduino and the code started working. 
Changed the code to print("{} {} {} {}".format(i-1,j-1,k-1,l-1)) Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to communicate with raspberry pi and arduino is using serial protocol. I have used this all the time.

There's a module in python for serial communication `pyserial`.

https://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-uart-communication-using-python-and-c

Comment: Thanks but since there are multiple devices on I2C, I have to stick to i2c. Though, thanks for replying.